# Usage of non continuous values in 'dist' for constraint random stimulus

Tags: system-verilog

System verilog support continuous range inside a 'dist'. 
For example

```
y dist {
[1:1000] :/ 40,
1500 :/ 60
}
```

Does it support multiple random elements. For example

```
{1,3,2,6} :/ 40
```

Is it possible to use 'inside' in 'dist' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for both questions is: no. Have a look at constraint distribution syntax in [SystemVerilog 3.1a
Language Reference Manual](http://www.eda.org/sv/SystemVerilog_3.1a.pdf) (12.4.4 Distribution)

Comment: The 3.1a LRM is outdated. The latest is [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) 18.5.4 *Distribution*